# Can somebody break this code up (explain) because I am not very good with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function functionl() {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('L1')).forEach(e => helper(e));
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('L2')).forEach(e => helper(e));
}

helper = (e) => {
  if (e.innerText == 'Hi') {
    e.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    e.innerText = 'Hello';
  } else {
    e.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    e.innerText = 'Hi';
  }
}
window.setInterval(functionl, 500);
```

This is a javascript that I changes blue to red and vice versa but can somebody explain me this code line by line because I am not very used to html and javascript? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `functionl` function finds each element with the given class and calls the `helper` function once for every such element, passing the found element as an argument. (It does this separately for the `L1` class and the `L2` class.)

The helper function uses that argument to identify the correct element and checks if the text inside the element is "Hi". If so, it switches the element's text to "Hello" and its color to blue; if not, it switches the element's text to "Hi" and its color to red.

The only reason either of these functions ever runs at all is because the final statement says to run `functionl` once every 500 milliseconds forever.

Comment: Thank you for your help but what I don't understand is whatvis foreach and how is it connected to helper

Comment: `forEach` is a function every `Array` knows about. (See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp).  `Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('L1'))` creates an Array of html elements (specifically, all the elements in the whole document that have 'L1' as one of their classes.) Now that we have an Array, we can use `.forEach` to loop through all of those elements, and "for each" one, do something...

Comment: The rules of how `forEach` works say that the "something" that we do for each item must be to call another function, and that  function can automatically know about the item from the Array that we are currently looking at. (We will look at every item in the Array, one at a time.) In `.forEach(e => helper(e))`, the `e` probably stands for element (but we could use `.forEach(foo => helper(foo))` and it would work the same, the name is not important.) It just means "whatever item we are looking at, send it to the `helper` function." Now when `helper` runs, it will also know about the current item

Comment: Thank you for explaining

Answer (score 0):

The person who wrote this code used a lot of shorthand notation. Until you're proficient with javascript, I wouldn't suggest using any shorthand notation. I added comments explaining the code below. I think the only thing you may have a problem with is the foreach, so go to the link below to find out more.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

```js
//This defines a function
function functionl() {
  //This gets all of the html tags with a class of L1 and goes through them in a loop
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('L1')).forEach(function(e) {
    //For each element with class of L1, this calls the function helper with the parameter of e. Look at line 13 now.
    helper(e);
  });
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('L2')).forEach(function(e) {
    helper(e);
  });
}

//This defines the helper() function
function helper(e) {
  //The code below checks if the text inside the element is 'Hi'
  if (e.innerText == 'Hi') {
    //If it is, it goes into this statement and changes the background color to blue and the text to hello
    e.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    e.innerText = 'Hello';
  } else {
    //The code goes into this statement if the text is not 'Hi'. If so, it changes the background color to red and the text to 'Hi'
    e.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    e.innerText = 'Hi';
  }

}
//This code executes every 0.5 seconds (500 milliseconds)
window.setInterval(functionl, 500);
```

```html
<div class="L1">Hi</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Helper is a function. The general syntax for a function is that you define it using `function helper(parameter) { code }` and the syntax to use it is `helper(parameter)`

Look at this link to learn more about functions: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp